# aggregation and display details in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have been learning MongoDB, while doing so I tried to implement the aggregation property for my database collection. I grouped the details of the employee based on their age and by using match function, my question is it possible to display the other key-value once they pass the age criteria?

```
db.employee.aggregate([
    { $match: { age: { $gte: 23 } } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id:'$age', 
            total: { $sum: 1 }, 
            name: { $addToSet: '$name' } 
        }
    }
])
```

and the output was like this

```
{ "_id" : 27, "total" : 2, "name" : [ "indhu", "logesh" ] }
{ "_id" : 26, "total" : 1, "name" : [ "keerthana" ] }
{ "_id" : 25, "total" : 1, "name" : [ "sneha" ] }
{ "_id" : 24, "total" : 1, "name" : [ "dhiva" ] }
{ "_id" : 23, "total" : 1, "name" : [ "elango" ] }
```

where `_id` denotes their age.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: instead of storing the name key by using addtoset attribute ,is there a way to display them in the output